# NodeJS REST API is not accessible from PHP CURL

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, curl, nginx

I have a NodeJS API to send push notifications(both GCM and APN) and its working smoothly.

Now I have an Admin Panel built in **PHP Codeigniter** and I want to call **Push API** using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Code goes like this

```
<?php 
 $url = "http://my_ip:9100/service/api/push";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

But it fails to connect and output is

> Failed to connect to my_ip: Permission denied

I've tested Push API from [Postman Client Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) and its working smoothly. If I try this in browser at least it'll enters the API method.

Both PHP Project and NodeJS Application are in same server( NGINX ) and I've tried 'localhost' in place of IP Address but its of no use.

What is that I'm missing here ?

- Anything that needs to be added while invoking request in cURL( tried many combinations for curl_setopt() )
- Any server setup that is blocking the Request from cURL

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allow CORS from your express server. This should only be the reason that refuses the connection from your curl. See this for allowing cors from express server. [CORS on ExpressJS](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)

Comment: I've added this before all GET and POST requests and still if I request from Postman or browser console gets printed but not from cURL

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });

Comment: There is a details explanation in github. Please read it. https://gist.github.com/iksose/9401758

there might be issue on your curl request, like sending the header, or the content type. If you come up with any solution, please share it. Thanks.